# Get all my videos (including private ones) using OAuth2

Tags: php, youtube-api

I currently have something working where it gets all of my videos based on my Youtube username. Now I need to have it pull my private videos as well.

How I need everything to work is as I upload a video to Youtube it automatically embeds on my webpage which is password protected.

I created my API key and also used the Oauth 2.0 Sandbox and was able to retrieve all of the videos, including private but I do not know how to integrate the Oauth with my current coding which is below:

```
    <?php


    // set feed URL
    $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/tprestinario/uploads';

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    ?>
      <h1><?php echo $sxml->title; ?></h1>
    <?php
    // iterate over entries in feed
    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
      $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

      // get video player URL
      $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
      $watch = $attrs['url']; 

      // get video thumbnail
      $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
      $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 


          // get <yt:duration> node for video length 
      $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'); 
      $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes(); 
      $length = $attrs['seconds']; 
        $videoid = $yt->videoid[0]; 

      ?>

        <div class="item">
            <h1><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $media->group->description; ?></p>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $videoid; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        </div>      
   <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [YouTube Data API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) that would be much easier.

Here's a nice example for this use case.

"https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/php/my_uploads.php"